# Order records so children appear just after parent in a multi-level hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, hierarchical-data

I have a table of items that contains all records of a multi-level hierarchy. So, there is a top level item and it has items below it which in turn has items below it and so on; also, there will be many top level items in this table.

My goal is to return records from this table such that each parent is followed by records of its children ( these children can be in any order) and each of the children is then followed by its children ( these children can be in any order) just after it and so on. I have created a SQLFiddle for this at: [SQLFiddle for this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/09b6d/6)

I have tried to obtain this using following query, but the third level hierarchy items are not appearing just after their parent.

```
select Id, ParentId, ChildLevel, 
CASE WHEN ChildLevel = 0 THEN Id 
     WHEN ChildLevel = 1 then Id  
     WHEN ChildLevel >  1 THEN ParentId END Num
from Items order by UltimateParentId, ChildLevel, Num ;
```

**Question**

Is there some way of getting children appear just after its parent in above sql fiddle?

Script for creating this table with data is as below.

```
create table Items ( Id int , ParentId int , ChildLevel int,     UltimateParentId int);

--I could have multiple hierarchy level for each top level item
--right now I am populating data at multiple levels for only one top level item
--but the table will consist of many top level items having their own hierarchy records

insert into Items (Id, ParentId, ChildLevel, UltimateParentId) values (1,0,0,0);
insert into Items (Id, ParentId, ChildLevel, UltimateParentId) values (2,1,1,1);
insert into Items (Id, ParentId, ChildLevel, UltimateParentId) values (3,1,1,1);
insert into Items (Id, ParentId, ChildLevel, UltimateParentId) values (4,1,1,1);
insert into Items (Id, ParentId, ChildLevel, UltimateParentId) values (5,3,2,1);
insert into Items (Id, ParentId, ChildLevel, UltimateParentId) values (7,2,2,1);
insert into Items (Id, ParentId, ChildLevel, UltimateParentId) values (6,3,2,1);
insert into Items (Id, ParentId, ChildLevel, UltimateParentId) values (8,4,2,1);
insert into Items (Id, ParentId, ChildLevel, UltimateParentId) values (9,3,2,1);
insert into Items (Id, ParentId, ChildLevel, UltimateParentId) values (10,2,2,1);
insert into Items (Id, ParentId, ChildLevel, UltimateParentId) values (11,4,2,1);
insert into Items (Id, ParentId, ChildLevel, UltimateParentId) values (12,11,3,1);
insert into Items (Id, ParentId, ChildLevel, UltimateParentId) values (13,5,3,1);
insert into Items (Id, ParentId, ChildLevel, UltimateParentId) values (14,11,3,1);
insert into Items (Id, ParentId, ChildLevel, UltimateParentId) values (15,5,3,1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not using strings for the ID/Parent, you can leverage the `hierarchyid` data type.

The R1,R2 and HierPath are optional in the final select.  The R1 and R2 indicate ownership ranges.  This facilitates aggregation and selection wihout having to go recursive.

**Example**

```
;with cteP as (
      Select ID
            ,ParentId 
            ,HierID = convert(hierarchyid,concat('/',ID,'/'))
      From   Items 
      Where  ParentId=0
      Union  All
      Select ID  = r.ID
            ,ParentId  = r.ParentId 
            ,HierID = convert(hierarchyid,concat(p.HierID.ToString(),r.ID,'/'))
      From   Items r
      Join   cteP p on r.ParentId  = p.ID)
Select R1    = Row_Number() over (Order By HierID)
      ,R2    = Row_Number() over (Order By HierID) + -1 + (Select count(*) From cteP where HierID.ToString() like A.HierID.ToString()+'%')
      ,Lvl   = HierID.GetLevel()
      ,ID
      ,ParentId
      ,HierID
      ,HierPath = HierID.GetDescendant ( null , null ).ToString()   
 From cteP A
 Order By A.HierID
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: @Sunil If your actual table is large and performance is critical.  Remove the R1 and R2 from the final select.

Comment: @Sunil Forgot to "complete" the R2 calculation.  See Updated answer

Comment: Yes, my table could be large. Its working as I have verified at following jsfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d8a4f/1. The second query is the one you gave, while the first one is what I had.

Comment: After removing R1 and R2 the execution time came down to 21 ms from something like 200 ms.

Comment: @Sunil CTE are great, but performance can suffer with large hierarchies.  Just curious how many rows in your hier?  There is another approach via a SP which can generate a 200K hier in 3 to 4 seconds

Comment: Instead of  Lvl column that you have in your query, I could simply use ChildLevel, if I include this column in CTE, that could further reduce extra work done by query.

Comment: Please let me know the `other` approach, which probably will not use hierarchyid data type. I am actually storing comments for a page in this items table, so each item is a comment and its children are the replies to parent comment. I am pretty sure that with time some pages could have a large number of comments i.e. items under it.

Comment: @Sunil I added a second answer tailored to your data.

Answer (score 1):

As Requested.  The following can generate a 200K hier in just a couple of seconds

> I should add... Where you see `Row_Number() over (Order By ID)`  I
>   used ID, but this can be any other field to determine the desired
>   presentation sequence.

**Example**

```
Select *,Lvl=1,Seq=cast(1000000+Row_Number() over (Order By ID) as varchar(900)) Into #TempBld from Items Where  ParentID = 0

Declare @Cnt int=1
While @Cnt<=30
    Begin
        Insert Into #TempBld 
        Select A.*,Lvl=B.Lvl+1,Seq=B.Seq+' '+ cast(1000000+Row_Number() over (Order By A.ID) as varchar(25))
         From  Items A
         Join  #TempBld B on (B.Lvl=@Cnt and A.ParentID=B.ID)
        Set @Cnt=@Cnt+1
    End

Select ID,R1=cast(Row_Number() over (Order by Seq) as int),Seq Into #TempR1 From #TempBld
Create Clustered Index idx on #TempR1 (Seq)
Select A.ID,R2 = Max(B.R1) Into  #TempR2 From  #TempBld A Join #TempR1  B on B.Seq Like A.Seq+'%' Group By A.ID

Select B.R1
      ,C.R2
      ,A.Lvl 
      ,A.ID
      ,A.ParentID
 From  #TempBld A
 Join  #TempR1  B on (A.ID=B.ID)
 Join  #TempR2  C on (A.ID=C.ID)
 Order By 1
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this.  In this method,  30 is number of levels in the hierarchy but I could increase it to something higher like 100.

Comment: @Sunil Sure.  My hierarchies would NEVER hit more than 20 levels, but I could see conversations going deeper

Comment: How would I achieve ordering of children for a parent using this? In original question, I had mentioned ordering of children is not important, but just in case I wanted to order the children i.e. replies to a comment by CreateDate.

Comment: @Sunil In the second answer see my yellow comment.  You can use any other desired field.   In the first answer, I assumed the ID was an identity which would maintain the sequence.

Comment: Ok. And why did you use 1000000 + Row_Number instead of just Row_Number?

Comment: @Sunil to normalize the sequence key Think of it as a cheap zero padding.

Comment: @Sunil For example.  You the following does not generate proper order Select * from (values ('1:00'),('200:25'),('1200:25')) A(v) Order by v

Comment: @Sunil Yet this does  Select * from (values ('10001:00'),('10200:25'),('11200:25')) A(v) Order by v

Comment: So, you end up with string values that can be easily ordered. Right?

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your excellent explanation. I am very clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
Common Table Expresion (CTE) can be recursive. If You use CTE You need only parrent ID. Check out https://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx